# ¿Como puedo obtener la posicion que ocupa un elemento dentro de su padre en js?

Tags: javascript, html

En javascript obtengo unos elementos con **queryselectorAll** y luego los itero con un **foreach**

```javascript
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
sections.forEach(s => {
    
    //obtener la posicion de s que ocupa en sections 
    //como si un array comun se tratara
})
```

de esa manera y necesito obtener la posicion de **s** en sections.

Comment: Usa el `foreach` con 2 argumentos `sections.forEach((s, index)=>{//....})`. El primer argumento `s` es el elemento y el segundo es la posición de `s` en `sections`.

Comment: Buen dato, probare.. ya que no sabia que el forEach tambien se podia usar de esa manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo valor que se pasa al forEach es el index

```js
let sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");

sections.forEach((Objeto,Index,TodosLoEvaluado)=>{
console.error(Index);
});
```

```html
<section>1</section>
<section>2</section>
<section>3</section>
<section>4</section>
<section>5</section>
```

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Justo un men me acababa de decir eso mismo, pero explicaste bien y complementaste con un ejemplo... gracias

Comment: @LexxCh Si esta respuesta ha cumplimentado tu pregunta plantéate aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa, para no dejar la pregunta pendiente eternamente, y así valorar el esfuerzo de quien te ha ayudado mejor, gracias.